# iOS app rejected after non consumable IAP implementation - Schedule 2, section 3.8(b)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, eula

My app is paid, and up to this update did not contain IAP.

In the new update I implemented a non consumable IAP, but during the review from Apple, the app, was rejected.

I received this message from reviewer:

- We noticed that your app did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement: 
  "3.8 You may offer auto-renewing subscriptions in select Territories using the In-App Purchase API subject to the terms of this Schedule 2, provided that...."

The problem is that in my app there aren't any type of subscription IAPs.

In the message they ask me to create a custom EULA.

But is it necessary?
I did not understand something or it is a mistake on their part?

Thanks